# HTML table alignment not working

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a table with one column and 3 rows. I want to take the heading of the table ie. Role in the center and along with that the line below Role, I want to make it small lengthwise. My row values are not aligned properly well. PLease find my attached screenshot[image]

My code

```
 <div style="text-align: center" class="form-group" ng-if="isNew">
                    <table class="table table-inverse">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-primary">
                            <th width="14%">
                                <span>Role</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    <table class="table table-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: none">
                                <input type="checkbox" name = "role" value = "Super" />Super</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: none">
                                <input type="checkbox" name = "role" value = "Power" />Power</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: none">
                                <input type="checkbox" name = "role" value = "Regular" />Regular</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, not layout.

Comment: @j08691 can you tell me how to format as I have mentioned?

Comment: Do you mean you want the forms on the same line and not underneath each other?

Answer (score 0):

I applied some CSS and wrapped your checkbox elements in a DIV. Please see the snippet.

```css
th {
  width: 100vw;
}
th > span {
  width: 14%;
 display: inline-block;
 border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
}
td {
  width: 100vw;
 text-align: center;
}
.checkbox {
  width: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.checkbox input {
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-if="isNew">
                    <table class="table table-inverse">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-primary">
                            <th>
                                <span>Role</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    <table class="table table-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name = "role" value = "Super" />Super
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name = "role" value = "Power" />Power
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name = "role" value = "Regular" />Regular
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```